# 'make' command is not linking files/library properly in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors, clang, cs50

I am a beginner and trying to learn C.
I am looking at the Harvard edX course, but I am running into an issue. Whenever I run `make test`, it is resulting in the following error:

```
cc     test.c   -o test
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_get_string", referenced from:
      _main in test-d904ae.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void) 
{
    string name = get_string("enter: ");
    printf("%s\n", name);
}
```

The `get_string` function is from the `cs50.h`. I know that there is way around this my using `clang test.c -o test -lc50`. However, it is being said that make does all of that, and I would like to know what is wrong so that I can use `make` instead of `clang test.c -o test -lcs50`.

Comment: *"it is being said that make does all of that,"* - I'd ask whomever/whatever is "saying" that. Make is as smart as you make it. It has some pretty nifty defaults, but integration with an external 3rd party library like cs50 isn't one of them. Makefiles are more or less introduced in cs50  [in pset3](https://cdn.cs50.net/2016/x/psets/3/pset3/pset3.html#searching), and in it you will find very quickly that specifying `-lcs50` is indeed the way to pull the lib in for consumption (unless you're consuming the actual *source*, which you're not).

Comment: Well, it is the instructor from the course that is stating that `make` automates the longer command of `clang ...`

Comment: It absolutely does. That's somewhat the point of a makefile and using make: automating that stuff. That doesn't meant you no longer have to provide library instruction; it just changes where/how it is provided. Rather than *you* having to provide it each and ever time you build via command line, you provide it *once* in a makefile and use make to handle it from there. Check out pset3. It demonstrates this.

Comment: The `pkg-config` utility helps finding right arguments for compiler and linker. Given that you had installed a source/binary package, and it has proper scripts to register itself with `pkg-config`.

Comment: `makefile` usually define variables for libs, include paths and such. For example one could use `pkg-config --libs libcurl`and assign its result string to some variable.